# Why connection line shows away from Div in JSPlumb?

Tags: jsplumb

This is **[my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XbcZv/13/)**

Query - When I am trying to establish the connnection between IDs A1 and B the connection pink line shows away from Div B. Below the pink line highlighted is away from Div B. This is the problem

**[image: ScreenShot]**

**JQuery**

```
//Setting up drop options
var targetDropOptions = {

};

connectorHoverStyle = {
    lineWidth: 7,
    strokeStyle: "#2e2aF8",
    cursor: 'pointer'
}

//Setting up a Target endPoint
var targetColor = "#316b31";
var targetEndpoint = {
    anchor: "LeftMiddle",
    endpoint: ["Dot", { radius: 8}],
    paintStyle: { fillStyle: targetColor },
    //isSource: true,
    scope: "green dot",
    connectorStyle: { strokeStyle: targetColor, lineWidth: 8 },
    connector: ["Flowchart", { curviness: 63}],
    maxConnections: -1,
    isTarget: true,
    dropOptions: targetDropOptions,
    connectorHoverStyle: connectorHoverStyle
};

//Setting up a Source endPoint
var sourceColor = "#ff9696";
var sourceEndpoint = {
    anchor: "RightMiddle",
    endpoint: ["Dot", { radius: 8}],
    paintStyle: { fillStyle: sourceColor },
    isSource: true,
    scope: "green dot",
    connectorStyle: { strokeStyle: sourceColor, lineWidth: 4 },
    connector: ["Flowchart", { curviness: 63}],
    maxConnections: -1,
    //            isTarget: true,
    dropOptions: targetDropOptions,
    connectorHoverStyle: connectorHoverStyle
};



jsPlumb.bind("ready", function () {

    jsPlumb.animate($("#A"), { "left": 50, "top": 100 }, { duration: "slow" });
    jsPlumb.animate($("#B"), { "left": 300, "top": 100 }, { duration: "slow" });
    jsPlumb.animate($("#C"), { "left": 540, "top": 100 }, { duration: "slow" });
    jsPlumb.animate($("#D"), { "left": 780, "top": 100 }, { duration: "slow" });

    var window = jsPlumb.getSelector('.window');
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint(window, targetEndpoint);
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint(window, sourceEndpoint);
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint(jsPlumb.getSelector('#A1'), sourceEndpoint, targetEndpoint);

    jsPlumb.draggable(window);

    jsPlumb.importDefaults({
        ConnectionOverlays: [
            ["Arrow", { location: 0.8}],
            ["Label", {
                location: 0.5,
                id: "label",
                cssClass: "aLabel"
            }]
        ]
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="A" class="a window" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: solid 1px;">
    <strong>A</strong>
    <div id="A1">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="B" class="b window" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: solid 1px;">
    <strong>B</strong>
</div>
<div id="C" class="c window" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: solid 1px;">
    <strong>C</strong>
</div>
<div id="D" class="d window" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: solid 1px;">
    <strong>D</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: you should add all your imports. so we can fidle this out

Comment: @joelharkes the jsFiddle (which I didn't see at first) has every library it needs, it should run fine...

Comment: @Pankajgarg well the problem is that the Endpoints are generated in the div that their "parents" are in... that said, your endpoint can only connect to the body and cannot even figure out where your other endpoint is. I don't know any solution to your problem, but place the `<action .../>` in the body and position it with css relative to the span it should be next to....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to have multiple Anchors on the same Div provided ID should be the attributes for those anchors somehow.

In order to accomplish this. I first removed the extra div. Now Suppose somebody wants to display two Source Anchors. For that I made modification in 
**jquery.jsPlumb-1.3.16-all-min.js** file

Following was the Original line of code in this file

```
this.makeNode = function (E, D) { 
    return f("circle", { cx: E[2] / 2, cy: E[3] / 2, r: E[2] / 2
}
```

Modification is below. **I am now adding id attributes to each anchor(circle)**.

```
this.makeNode = function (E, D) { 
    var attr = $('#'+obj[0].endpoint.elementId).attr('actionID');
    return f("circle", { cx: E[2] / 2, cy: E[3] / 2, r: E[2] / 2, id: attr 
}
```

**How am I getting the value of id ?**

In, the Div shown above in the query, I added an Attribute **Action** and assigned some ID that I want to assign. Like below

```
jsPlumb.getSelector('#first').attr('actionID', 'p1');
```

**and finally adding the EndPoint**

```
jsPlumb.addEndpoint(jsPlumb.getSelector('#first'), sourceEndpoint);
```

Similarly, I can assign as many distinct Anchors in terms of IDs as much required.

```
jsPlumb.getSelector('#first').attr('actionID', 'p3');
jsPlumb.addEndpoint(jsPlumb.getSelector('#first'), [TopMiddle]);
```

**How will you assign the Source ID and target ID on Connection ?**

```
jsPlumb.bind("jsPlumbConnection", function (CurrentConnection) {
    if (CurrentConnection.connection.targetId == 
                                    CurrentConnection.connection.sourceId)
        jsPlumb.detach(CurrentConnection.connection);
    else {
        var obj = CurrentConnection.sourceEndpoint.canvas.children[0].firstChild.id;
        init(CurrentConnection.connection, obj);
    }
});

init = function (connection, CircleID) {
    connection.getOverlay("label").setLabel(CircleID + "-" + connection.targetId);
};
```

Hope this will be helpful to those users facing the same issue...